# mysql permission to access (decrypt) records in table

Tags: mysql, encryption

I will try to make up a simple example, which shows the problem I face:

Let there be a table in my mysql database, which contain private messages of a messaging system for users of an internet platform. The table would simply look like that:

```
From    To    Text
1       2     "Hello, Mr. 2"
2       1     "Hello back!"
```

For security reasons I want to encrypt the `text` column of this table, so that, even if the data got stolen, it remains a hard task to decrypt the text.

My first idea was to use the users password as a key to encrypt his/hers messages, but then I recognized, that there are two people in need of permission to access one particular record. So I was wondering which is a frequent practice to proceed? Has mysql `built-in` methods, going further than e.g. `AES_ENCRYPT()`, for public/private key approaches? I am really not an expert on this, so if there are common pitfalls, thanks for mention them!

Comment: Where do you intend to store the key?  If your server has been hacked, won't the hacker have access to it and therefore be able to decrypt such data?

Comment: Also note that when using encryption on data level instead of transport level (what is usually done) you cannot offer any search inside that text any more...

Comment: as I said, I did not want to store the key but just wanted to use the users password as the encryption key. @arkascha I am aware of the problem, that I cannot use these columns for any other task. I mean in this scenario I want no one else but these two users have any chance to view this record. But thanks for mentioning!

Comment: @arkascha you would not recommend, to apply `data level encryption` because it is totally unusual to do so? I thought that encryption in database is also used, because mysql still provides functions for encryption. For instance using password hashing in database is I guess quite widely used. What are the main arguments leading to the decision whether to use `transport level encryption`(which I already applied) or `data level encryption`? or even both?

Comment: I'd say that is of limited use in the end, so why would one want to do it then. As pointed out by others the problem is the encryption key being stored alongside the database. About passwords: don't confuse those two things. passwords are usually _not_ stored encrypted, but as a `salted hash`. That is a big difference if it comes to security. As a rule of thumb I'd say: invest the effort into securing the server itself (application, system, network) instead of trying to enhance security on a level where you already know the effect is of very limited use.

Comment: If you're not storing the key, how do you perform decryption?  In the client?